# How to solve issue "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

I have trained my custom model named `best.pt` and I am trying to use it in python code. It seems to be working fine but not sure when closing the script it gives below error

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Python script is very straightforward reading the frames from webcam, loading the model and performing the inferencing. Below line is loading the model

```
model = torch.hub.load('/home/andrew/yolov5', 'custom', path=modelDir, source='local')
```

I have also cloned the `yolov5` repository in location `/home/thingtrax/yolov5`. When I commented the above line, it do not show the above error. Am I importing it in a wrong way?

Comment: File a bug report? There's nothing in the single line of code that causes this, so it must be in some other code. Prepare a [mcve] as well and perhaps run the code in a debugger.